# joomla 3 translation "search only" in search

Tags: joomla3.0

I have problem with translation "search only" (`"area-categories/area-contacts/etc"`) options in "search" component.

Terms for this area do not support the location and I can not find where to set them up.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you see? Usually translations reside in language files and there is a proper way to override them

Comment: http://habrastorage.org/storage2/811/1ae/3ae/8111ae3ae7943802e11ef39148341f6d.png